# Run python window app in startx (x window)

Tags: linux, x11, python, x-server, startx

I am running the python window app in startx, it works fine, but there is one issue. the issue will be in the next two images.
-First image, Python app running in Linux GUI [window app in GUI](https://github.com/TarikVUT/Store-/blob/main/images/in%20GUI.png) 
-Second image, Python app running in Linux startx  [window app in startx](https://github.com/TarikVUT/Store-/blob/main/images/In%20startx.png)
As you can see the window app in startx is losing its frame. 
I have added the below code to **.xinitrc**

```
#!/bin/bash
#to set mouse cursor
xsetroot -cursor_name arrow
#to run startpython.py
exec python /home/GUI/startpython.py
```

What is the way to make the window in (startx) look like window in GUI (enable the frame around the window), without the frame I can close the window using (x).
**Any idea?**

Comment: The frame you're referring to is provided by something called the window manager, which you'd normally install as part of the desktop environment (gnome, kde, etc). Which is why it is there when you've run the code in desktop environment, but not when you're just running it via `startx`. You could look into starting a window manager as a part of your `.xinitrc` and then starting the python code. You may get a better answer if you elaborate on what your end goal for this is.

Comment: Thank you Natolio for your answer. First, I disabled gdm in the system. The goal is to be able to run python (a GUI application) in startx and (a python GUI application) should look the same as if it was running in gdm

Comment: I  believe that the default window manager for gnome is called mutter. Try executing `mutter` and then executing your python in your startx.

Comment: Thank you **Natolio**